# Is it possible to Display threshold value in sencha bar chart

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-charts

Is it possible to display threshold value line in the sencha bar charts. As my requirements is to show the threshold value as a vertical line on the bar chart, so that the user can easily able to find which are out of limits.

Please help me regarding this....

Thanks,

Nag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a line series to return the data that will then make the line series draw a line. I add the threshold value dynamically to each row in the store. My code is

```
  data: [
    {'name':'Jhon, wilson', 'data1':10, 'data2':5},
    {'name':'Miller Andrew', 'data1':20, 'data2':5},
    {'name':'Roger Federer', 'data1':30, 'data2':5},
    {'name':'Prashant', 'data1':40, 'data2':5},
    {'name':'Graham Smith', 'data1':50, 'data2':5},
    {'name':'Jhon, wilson1', 'data1':10, 'data2':5},
    {'name':'Miller Andrew2', 'data1':20, 'data2':5},

    ],
```

in the series i mentioned

```
       {
            type: 'line',
            axis: 'bottom',
            showMarkers: false,
            xField: 'data2',
            yField: 'data1',
            style: {
                    lineWidth: 10,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    fill: '#18428E',
                   stroke: '#18428E',
                  'stroke-width': 10,

            },

        }
```